# ss doesn't display socket info related to the process opening SOL_SOCKET

Tags: linux, lsof, unix-sockets, ss

I run a python code inside docker container performing the following calls

```
import socket as s,subprocess as sp;s1=s.socket(s.AF_INET,s.SOCK_STREAM);
s1.setsockopt(s.SOL_SOCKET,s.SO_REUSEADDR, 1);s1.bind(("0.0.0.0",9001));s1.listen(1);c,a=s1.accept();
```

I'm trying to get info using `ss` and see the open sockets, but can't get them

```bash
docker run --rm --publish 9001:9001 -it --name python-app sample-python-app reverseshell.py

docker inspect --format='{{.State.Pid}}' python-app
1160502

> sudo ss -a -np | grep 9001 
tcp   LISTEN    0      4096                                                                              0.0.0.0:9001                0.0.0.0:*        users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1160459,fd=4))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
tcp   LISTEN    0      4096                                                                                 [::]:9001                   [::]:*        users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1160467,fd=4))
```

however lsof gives me more info:

```
> sudo lsof -p 1160502       
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.portal file system /run/user/1000/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
python  1160502 dmitry  cwd    DIR 0,1364      108    19497 /workspace
python  1160502 dmitry  rtd    DIR 0,1364      188      256 /
python  1160502 dmitry  txt    REG 0,1364     6120     6529 /layers/paketo-buildpacks_cpython/cpython/bin/python3.10
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30              6529 /layers/paketo-buildpacks_cpython/cpython/bin/python3.10 (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30              9492 /layers/paketo-buildpacks_cpython/cpython/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30              9518 /layers/paketo-buildpacks_cpython/cpython/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/fcntl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30              9514 /layers/paketo-buildpacks_cpython/cpython/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/array.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30              9527 /layers/paketo-buildpacks_cpython/cpython/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/select.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30              9520 /layers/paketo-buildpacks_cpython/cpython/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/math.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30              9499 /layers/paketo-buildpacks_cpython/cpython/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30               634 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30               692 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.27.so (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30               619 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30               670 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30               609 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30              6705 /layers/paketo-buildpacks_cpython/cpython/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0 (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30               591 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30              3735 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive (path dev=0,32, inode=1544914)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30              1365 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry  mem    REG   0,30              1091 /usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE (stat: No such file or directory)
python  1160502 dmitry    0u   CHR  136,0      0t0        3 /dev/pts/0
python  1160502 dmitry    1u   CHR  136,0      0t0        3 /dev/pts/0
python  1160502 dmitry    2u   CHR  136,0      0t0        3 /dev/pts/0
python  1160502 dmitry    3u  sock    0,8      0t0 75159952 protocol: TCP
```

at least I have this line showing that fd=3 opens socket [75159952] but without actual port number.

```bash
python  1160502 dmitry    3u  sock    0,8      0t0 75159952 protocol: TCP
```

so how to find with `ss` information about open socket over port 9001 that is not `docker-proxy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch to the correct network namespace first, because socket state is per namespace (namely [per network namespace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/network_namespaces.7.html)). For example by using [`nsenter`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html). `sudo` has to be moved first, because `nsenter` also requires privileges. In one line (and using `ss`'s own filtering features) this becomes:

```
sudo nsenter -t $(docker inspect --format='{{.State.Pid}}' python-app) --net -- \
    ss -a -np sport == 9001
```